# Proof: $\alpha_1>\alpha_2$ in a triangle

Tags: geometry

I have to proof in a triangle, that $\alpha_1>\alpha_2$ holds. The inner point P (from where I draw the smaller triangle) is set randomly.

[image]

Does anyone have a suggestion where I have to start?

Greetings

Comment: You're probabaly missing one piece of vital information: The random point $P$ is supposed to be *inside* the original triangle?

Comment: Yes, of course you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that the origin triangle is $\triangle ABC$, and the inner point is $P$, where $\alpha_1 = \angle BPC$, $\alpha_2 = \angle BAC$. Supposing that $D$ is the intersection of $AP$ and $BC$, we have
$\angle BPC = \angle BPD + \angle DPC = \angle BAP + \angle ABP + \angle CAP + \angle ACP$
$= \angle BAC + \angle ABP + \angle ACP > \angle BAC$, Q.E.D.

Comment: I tohught about this answer a few days but I can't find an explanation for $\angle BPD + \angle DPC = \angle BAP + \angle ABP + \angle CAP + \angle ACP$ perhaps you can give a hint?

Comment: See here http://www.onlinemathlearning.com/exterior-angle-theorem.html, or have I made some mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Each of $\,\alpha_1\,,\,\alpha_2\,$ equals $\,180 - (\beta_1+\beta_2)\,$ , with $\beta_i$ being the other two angles in the big (in the little red) triangle. As the other two angles of $\,\alpha_1\,$ are each less than the other two angles of $\,\alpha_2\,$ we get what we want.

Comment: There is nothing more to do? I thought I have to argue, why the angles are smaller...

Comment: @Daniels Of course you have! The other two angles of $\alpha_1$ are smaller than the corresponding ones of $\alpha_2$ since they're partial to them...or in other words: each of the other angles corres. to $\alpha_2$ equals the corres. angle of $\alpha_1$ ***plus*** a little more...you can mark this in your diagram, to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**: Draw a line that passes through the vertices of the two angles and the opposite side.

Comment: (+1) Good Hint ! why the heck was it downvoted ?! :o